# best practice for bootstrap modals and RESTful links in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out what is the best practice to create different forms inside bootstrap modal, while still maintaining RESTful links in rails 4.

For example, lets say that I have two forms one for sign in and one for sign up,
at the moment they each have their own path
for Sign up:

```
server/users/new
```

for Sign in

```
server/session/new
```

this is actually being masked as a root_path, so the user will see `server` in the url

what would be the best approach to include these two inside a bootstrap modal and still keep their RESTful paths